# Error: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a function `api` inside the method `onSubmit`, which make request to the server:

```
onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              if(Array.isArray(res)){              
                  setErrorMessage(res[0].message);                  
              } else {
                 const token = res.token.token;   
                 localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);     
                 history.push("/home");
             }
          } catch(e) { 
              console.error(e);
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
       },  
    });
```

Function `api` is in a separate file and looks like this:

```
export const api = async (url, args) => { 

  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${url}`, {
   ...args,
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8 ",
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      ...args.headers,  
    },
  });
      
 return response.json();      
}
```

This function was created simply for convenience. But now I dont need this function. I need that code from `api` was inside method `onSubmit`. That is, that the function `api` not exist at all.

And I did it:

```
onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const resf = await fetch(`${apiUrl}api/auth/register`, {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues),
                  headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8 ",
                    "Accept": 'application/json', 
                  }
              });
              const res = resf.json();
              
              if (Array.isArray(res)){              
                  setErrorMessage(res[0].message);                  
              } else {
                 const token = res.token.token;   
                 localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);     
                 history.push("/home");
             }
          } catch(e) { 
              console.error(e);
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
       },  
    });
```

But I have error:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined**

## Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `await` for `resf.json()` because calling `.json()` gets you another promise for the body of the http response that is yet to be loaded.

```
const res = await resf.json();
```